# How to track facebook mobile app install source

Tags: android, ios, facebook

I plan to have different marketing houses for a single app.

Is it possible to track from which facebook ad did the mobile install came from and how?

what would be the best way to achieve that?
I want to know, if possible, what was the source for app install. 
Even if someone markets an app via flyer or tv ad, is it possible to first redirect the marketing to a facebook ad, and if opened on mobile it will offer installation. Then I will be able to tell the source of marketing

I am interested in android way of doing this also

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear but Are you looking something like this ? You may track the installation from ad click source. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads/

Comment: I read that. Is it possible to have two differents ads and to track them separately